# How to submit a contact form via custom button using "href" code?

Tags: html, forms, class, submit

For my website I'm working on a contact form, which works. But I want the submit button to be like other buttons on my site, meaning I want it to be styled like the code below.

However, I can't get it to submit via a "href" code.

I've tried applying answers on similar questions but haven't had any luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**THE STYLE FOR THE SUBMIT BUTTON I WANT TO USE:**

```
<div class="section-buttons">   
<p class="button layer" data-depth="0.10" ><a href = "I WANT THIS TO SUBMIT THE FORM"       
class="y1 knop roll swing"><span class="g1">SUBMIT</span><span class="g2">SUBMIT</span>  
</a></p>     
</div>
```

**THE FORM CODE:**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label></label>
        <input name="name" required placeholder="Name">


        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="E-mail">


        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required placeholder="Message"> 
        </textarea>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot for the quick replies. Really appreciated.
Celt, your solution definitely brings me close to the solution.

It does indeed bring me to the form.php but it doesn't seem to submit the actual data to an email address.

Could it be that my PHP file (forms.php) does something wrong with the new code? I'm guessing the last part "if ($_POST['submit'])" doesn't quite work with this new approach? Any help?

Sorry for the noobness.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: website.com'; 
$to = 'email@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
echo '<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message  
again.</p>'; 
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="y1 knop roll swing" onClick="document.getElementById('formName').submit(); return false;"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great and quick answer. Much appreciated. It does bring me to forms.php but doesn't actual submit any data. Any thoughts? (see edit).

Comment: Edited the answer there, give it a go.